# Trying to implement a trie using a list in Python

Tags: python, trie

Hey there this is my first post here!
So I am trying to implement a trie tree using a list in Python, however I am facing some difficulties. 
This is my code:

```
trie_root = []
list = ['to','toe']
for word in list:
if word == "":
    continue
else:
    cur_node = trie_root
    for letter in word:
        if len(cur_node)<1:
            x=[letter]
            cur_node.append(x)
            cur_node=x
        else:
            for i in cur_node:

                if letter == i[0]:
                    x=[i[0:]]
                    cur_node=x

                    break

                else:

                    x=[letter]
                    cur_node.append(x)  # This line inserts the next letter in the trie

                    cur_node = x
                    break
    cur_node.append('$')  # This line terminates the word in the trie

print(trie_root)
```

However, when I print trie_root, the output is `[['t', ['o', '$']]]`

Where is the missing 'e' from 'toe' in the output? How do I add it in there?
However if my list contains words that start with different letters, for example 'jar' and 'toe' it gives the right output: `[['j', ['a', ['r', '$']]], ['t', ['o', ['e', '$']]]]`

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Two comments. First, your indentation isn't right, in the version I am reading. Please make sure it's displaying as you mean it. For instance, your first if-else should be indented one level, right? Second comment: Under `for i in cur_node`, both the `if` and the `else` include a `break`. That means that in no case does the `for i in cur_node` proceed past the first entry in `cur_node`. Surely not what you want.

Comment: @D-Von but if my list has words that don't start with the same character, for example if my list has the words 'jar', and 'toe',  it gives the right output:                      [['j', ['a', ['r', '$']]], ['t', ['o', ['e', '$']]]]

Comment: @samyriana: What would be the expected behavior for the `list` that you have?

Comment: That's useful information for the original question, so I suggest you add it there. But how does it respond to my two points? Your telling me that the case for which tries are not efficient works correctly doesn't say much about the case when the efficiency kicks in.

Comment: @NickilMaveli [['t', ['o', '$',['e','$']]]]

Comment: Using `list` as an identifier is a bad idea since it overwrites a built-in identifier. Also, your indentation is still off.

Comment: I tried re-writing this last night, and found it quite difficult to keep track of things within these lists. Why are you using lists? Why not use a custom "node" object?

Comment: Down vote since your code snippet still is syntactically incorrect.